# Best SERVERLESS way to feed data from multiple Chrome extensions to a single Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-app-engine, google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, webhooks, google-apps

I have a Chrome browser plugin which performs like a social media posts bookmarks collector (a click on a post captures it's author username, text, date, permalink and the plugin user who owns it). I'm looking for the most efficient, safest and **SERVERLESS** way to have [potentially] thousands of plugin end-users update, for each individual click on a post, a line in a Google spreadsheet.

With my limited knowledge I narrowed the options to webhooks:

1. Create a Google Apps simple webhook app that will listen to plugin packets.
2. Have the end-user plugins send each social-media post click data in JSON to the webhook.
3. Have the webhook Google App publish an RSS feed with all the data collected
4. Have the Google Spreadsheet regularly check for new RSS entries and update a new line for each.

What i'm not sure of is 1) whether a simple webhook can be created using Google Apps? 2) can this method be secure enough to prevent non-plugin entries to the RSS feed? and 3) is there a simpler more efficient way of achieving this end?

Your help will be much appreciated :-)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily create Webhooks in Google Apps Script through the use of [Webapps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web). As an example:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  if (e.postData && e.postData.type == 'application/json') {
    var data = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

    var author = data['author'];
    var text = data['text'];
    var date = data['date'];
    var permalink = data['permalink'];
    var user = data['user'];
    // (...)
  }
```

This example code will parse the data received through a JSON post request. Afterwards, you can insert it to your Spreadsheet and generate an RSS feed using [XmlService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service) (for more information on how to do it see [this](https://ctrlq.org/code/20066-rss-feed-with-google-apps-script) blog post). The RSS feed can be served using the `doGet()` method.

Comment: Can the Google Script Web App provide a unique URL for the plugins to call to?

Comment: @EladRatson that is correct. After you deploy your webapp, you will get a URL you can use to send requests to it.

Comment: Thank you very much that helped me a lot